# At least how many residents of the country have the same birthday?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, birthday

I am trying to solve a pigeonhole question in discrete mathematics.

> Let's suppose that a country has 11.000.000 people.  **At least** how many residents of the country have the same birthday?

Take into consideration that leap years exist.

What I did is:

Let's suppose we have 2021.  I take $\frac{10.000.000 \cdot 2021}{11.000.000} =1838$.

I believe I am wrong.

Comment: The problem is not concerned with people who died thousands of years ago (and why exclude those born before year $0$?).  We are only interested in the $11$ million current residents.  And we only care about the birthday as a day, the year of birth is to be ignored.

Comment: as you said I must be cared only for date and month of the residents?

Comment: Well, that's how I read the question. If you had any other interpretation, please edit your post to include it.

Comment: @maikl

I just wanna say that I was in exactly the same boat. Many questions have some untold assumptions, which you get used to after you encounter enough problems. But without knowing those assumptions(e.g. same day of the same year or same day of any year) you might get different answer from the book.

Comment: There are $366$ days in the year (counting February $29$).  There is no need to approximate (not all months have $31$ days).

Comment: @maikl Here's a quick tutorial of the pigeonhole principle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMpSKjK9clA

Comment: 11milion/366=0.0300546448. is this the right answer?

Comment: You believe that $11$ million divided by $366$ is around $.03$?  Like I said, take your time, and think about the calculation you are doing.  It should be clear to you that the right answer isn't that $.03$ people were born on each day.

Comment: sorry calculator wrong , it is  300546448.More specific 30054.6

Comment: Ok, that looks better.  Now, how do you use that to get an actual answer to the question?  Keep in mind that it doesn't make sense to say that $.6$ of a person was born on some particular day.

Comment: if we do the [ ] then it is 30055?

Comment: Good!  After all, if exactly $30,054$ people were born on each day, that would only account for $30054\times 366=10,969,710$ people, which is too small.  So, some day must have at least $30,055$.  And that's your answer!

Comment: @lulu thank you lulu for helping me :) amaizing math calculations thanks

Comment: I note that I've cleared several comments to this post. Anyone inclined should feel welcome to distill the answer from the comments and post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

*Just to give an answer for completeness based on lulu's comments:*

There are $366$ possible birthdays and $\frac{11,000,000}{366}\approx 30054.6$

If each day had at most $30054$ people with that day as their birthday, then you would have at most $30054 \times 366 = 10,969,710$ people in total.

But there are more people than that, so you must have a day with at least $30055$  people with that day as their birthday.